# Converting non-numeric date to individual month,day, year components, and combining into one cell as datevalue

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

I have a date that Excel does not see as a value, I parsed out the month, day, year components into three separate cells, and converted to values, and now need to combine them in one cell to be seen as a date value

Comment: I think we need to see some examples.

Answer (score 2):

Where are your parsed out values of year, month and day stored?

Assuming Year is in A2, Month in A3 and Day in A4 just try simply putting this formula on (for example) A5 cell:

```
=DATE(A2,A3,A4)
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot add a comment, but a slight "fleshing out" to danicotra's answer would be to point out that DATE() does not use "windowing" like, say, directly entering a date into a cell would.

Making sure the year input is four digits avoids the issue.

(  DATE(18,06,23") produces 6/23/1918, not the 6/23/2018 one might have expected.  )